# need help executing function in my object with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

Need a little help making animal speak in program below using knockoutjs.

https://jsfiddle.net/cLu38jjt/6/

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: animals">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: type"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" data-bind="value: 'speak', click: speak" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function animal(name, talk) {
    var self = this;
    self.type = name;
    self.speak = function (talk) {
        alert(speak);
    }
}

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.animals = ko.observableArray([
    new animal('dog', 'woof'),
    new animal('cat', 'meow')]);

}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
alert(speak);
```

you should have

```
alert(talk);
```

Comment: It alerts with an object type instead of the string value?

Comment: Your fiddle works as expected for me. The dog alerts with woof, the cat with meow.